# How to change the order of ggplot2 facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame "pd.long" with following structure:

```
> str(pd.long)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Site   : Factor w/ 12 levels "BED","BEU","EB",..: 8 9 10 3 11 1 6 7 5 4 ...
$ Month  : Factor w/ 12 levels "Dec","Jan","Feb",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Density: int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
```

I have constructed bar-plots with this piece of code:

```
ggplot(pd.long, aes(x=Month, y=Density, fill=Site))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "darkgray")+
xlab("Month") + ylab("Number")+
facet_wrap(~Site, nrow = 3, scales = "free")
```

and the graphs look like this:

Everything was fine until I noticed that the levels of variable "Site" are not in the order of my choice. ggplot orders them alphabetically, as follows:

```
pd.long$Site
Levels: BED BEU EB KAD KAU KB KER KOA KOB KOO PNS RO
```

However, I want them to be in the same order in which they appear in the variable column i.e.

```
KOA KOB KOO EB  PNS BED KB  KER KAU KAD RO  BEU
```

Any help will highly be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: You might find the **forcats** function `fct_inorder` useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

reorder the factors

```
pd.long$Site <- factor(pd.long$Site,levels=c("KOA","KOB","KOO","EB","PNS","BED","KB","KER","KAU","KAD","RO","BEU"))
```

or more general answer where the order is based on the first apperance in the `Site` column :

```
pd.long$Site <- factor(pd.long$Site,levels=unique(pd.long$Site))
```